# How to detect if coordinates are within a SKEWED rectangle?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to submit variable coordinates and calculate if they are within the 4 point coordinates of a skewed rectangle.
The points across range from 10.0 to 20.0 and points up are 9.3 to 9.9

Like this illustration... Calculate the position of (*) with the skewed rectangle. Which would be something like (9.7, 16.2)

```
                 +  10.2
             -   |
         -       |
9.9  +           |
     |     (*)   +  9.6
     |       - 
     |   -      20.0
9.3  +

    10.0
```

I have an example of finding coordinates within a simple rectangle.. but Wondering the most efficient way to modify for my needs.

```
function isInside(x, y, z1, z2, z3, z4) {x1 = Math.min(z1, z3){
    x2 = Math.max(z1, z3);
    y1 = Math.min(z2, z4);
    y2 = Math.max(z2, z4);
    if ((x1 <= x ) && ( x <= x2) && (y1 <= y) && (y <= y2)) {
        console.log(x1 + "," + x + "," + x2);
        console.log(y1 + "," + y + "," + y2);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

Comment: Just remove the skew by putting all coordinates values through a linear transform, then use the normal rectangle boundary algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare x coordinate for horisontal check and compare sin of angles for vertical check

```js
function isInside(x, y, leftBottom, rightBottom, leftUp, rightUp) {
    
    var rectAngleSin = (rightBottom.y - leftBottom.y) / (rightBottom.x - leftBottom.x);
    var lbToPointSin = (y - leftBottom.y) / (x - leftBottom.x);
    var luToPointSin = (y - leftUp.y) / (x - leftUp.x);
    
    var isInsideHor = x >= leftBottom.x && x <= rightBottom.x;
    var isInsideVert = luToPointSin <= rectAngleSin && lbToPointSin >= rectAngleSin;
    
    return isInsideHor && isInsideVert;
};

var leftBottom = {x: 10, y: 9.3};
var leftUp = {x: 10, y: 9.9};
var rightBottom  = {x: 20, y: 9.6};
var rightUp = {x: 0, y: 10.2};

console.log(isInside(16.2, 9.7, leftBottom, rightBottom, leftUp, rightUp));
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! 